# ¿Cual es el error en mi codigo de javascript?

Tags: javascript, web

Hola que tal espero me puedan ayudar.

Lo que sucede es que intento validar un formulario con javascript pero el código no se ejecuta o me marca un error como este:

en chrome:

> validate_frm_login_admin.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
>       at validarCampos (validate_frm_login_admin.js:8)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementById.onclick (validate_frm_login_admin.js:20)

Lo intento hacer es, que si el campo usuario o contraseña de mi formulario están vacíos se aplique una clase llamada error que hace que se las cajas tengan un color rojo de fondo.

mi código:

```js
"use strict";
    
    function validarCampos() {
     var usrAdmin = document.getElementById('tb_admin_usr');
     var psswdrAdmin = document.getElementById('tb_admin_psswrd');
    
     if (usrAdmin.length == 0 || psswdrAdmin.length == 0) {
      usrAdmin.classList.add('error');
      psswdrAdmin.classList.add('error');
      return false;
     }
     else{
      usrAdmin.classList.remove('error');
      psswdrAdmin.classList.remove('error');
    
      return true;
     }
    }
    
    document.getElementById('btn-submit').onclick = function() {validarCampos()};
```

```css
.error{
        background-color: #ff7675;
        border: 1px solid #d63031;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/frm_admin_styles.css">
        <script src="../js/validate_frm_login_admin.js"></script>
        <title>Iniciar Sesión</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main class="main-content">
            <div class="container">
                <form action="" method="post" class="frm-admin_login">
                    <label for="tb_admin_usr">Usuario:</label>
                    <div class="frm_group">
                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="tb_admin_usr" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Usuario">
                    </div>
                    <label for="tb_admin_psswrd">Contraseña:</label>
                    <div class="frm_group">
                        <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
                        <input type="password" id="tb_admin_psswrd" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Contraseña">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="btn-submit">Acceder</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
    </html>
```

la verdad no se cual sea el problema hice el código de maneras diferentes y nada, no se ejecuta, si alguien me diera una mano se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: estas declarando este javascript al  final de tu HTML?

Comment: Lo hace en el head, pero no creo que tenga que ver ya que asocia la función a un método onClick.

Comment: yo creo que si tiene que ver por que replique su ejercicio, puse el js al final y funciona sin problemas

Comment: Lo asocia a un método `onClick`, pero para asociarlo recoge el id del botón, si lo hace en el `head` el botón no estará creado todavía

Comment: exacto, por eso la pregunta, con moverlo al final debería bastar o no @Rabegi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya te han dicho hay varios errores y alguna mala práctica, pero de todo se aprende!

1. Tus elementos input:text y input:password no tienen la etiqueta name, es más fácil identificar los inputs de un formulario a través de la etiqueta name que por ID/Clase. Además de que si necesitas serializar un formulario, serán obligatorias.
2. Añade los scripts al final de body para que carguen en última instancia
3. Con usrAdmin.length no evalúas que la cadena esté vacía, te devolverá un undefined. Tendrás que usar usrAdmin.value.length o usrAdmin.value
4. Esa función sólo sirve para validar esos campos exclusivamente, algo que puede ser un problema a la hora de crear y validar más formularios. Intenta pensar siempre teniendo en mente una posible re utilización de código para ahorrarte tiempo.
5. No es necesario esperarte a que se construya todo el DOM o el contenido de la web por completo porque sólo enviarás el formulario cuando hagas click.

   ```
       const validarCampos = (form) => {
           const adminUser = form.tb_admin_usr
           const adminPsswrd = form.tb_admin_psswrd
           if (!adminUser.value) {
               adminUser.classList.add('error')
               return false
           } else if (!adminPsswrd.value) {
               adminPsswrd.classList.add('error')
               return false
           } else {
               adminUser.classList.remove('error')
               adminPsswrd.classList.remove('error')
               return true
           }
       }

       document.getElementById('frm-admin_login').onsubmit = function (e) {
           e.preventDefault()
           if (validarCampos(this)) {
               this.submit()
           }
       }
   ```

Si te interesa, te dejo una alternativa a tu código bastante más sencilla de entender desde mi punto de vista. Necesitarías añadir los atributos name dentro de los inputs y un id a ese fomulario para validarlo como formulario único. Esas validaciones las puedes utilizar como funciones también.

```
    // Si quieres validar el formulario por ID única
    document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (this.atributo_name_form.value && this.atributo_name_form.value) {
            // TODO 
            console.log('Los campos no están vacíos')
            this.submit()
        } else {
            // Manejo de errores
            console.log('Algún campo vacío')
        }
    })

    // Si quieres validar todos los formularios con la clase frm-admin_login
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        const forms = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.frm-admin_login'))
        forms.forEach(form => {
            form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                if (this.name.value && this.surname.value) {
                    console.log('no están vacío')
                    this.submit()
                } else {
                    console.log('algún campo vacío')
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo he visto dos problemas principalmente; en el formulario pones el método post a una acción vacía y en el if en el que compruebas la longitud de user y password, mides la longitud del elemento no del valor de este.

Lo que han comentado otros de poner el script al final, tienen razón, es una buena práctica y deberías hacerlo.

```js
"use strict";
    
    function validarCampos() {
     var usrAdmin = document.getElementById('tb_admin_usr');
     var psswdrAdmin = document.getElementById('tb_admin_psswrd');
      
     if (usrAdmin.value.length == 0 || psswdrAdmin.value.length == 0) {
      usrAdmin.classList.add('error');
      psswdrAdmin.classList.add('error');
      return false;
     }
     else{
          usrAdmin.classList.remove("error");
        psswdrAdmin.classList.remove("error");
    
      return true;
     }
    }
    
    document.getElementById('btn-submit').onclick = function() {validarCampos()};
```

```css
.error{
        background-color: #ff7675;
        border: 1px solid #d63031;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/all.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/frm_admin_styles.css">
        <title>Iniciar Sesión</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main class="main-content">
            <div class="container">
                <form class="frm-admin_login">
                    <label for="tb_admin_usr">Usuario:</label>
                    <div class="frm_group">
                        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="tb_admin_usr" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Usuario">
                    </div>
                    <label for="tb_admin_psswrd">Contraseña:</label>
                    <div class="frm_group">
                        <i class="fas fa-key"></i>
                        <input type="password" id="tb_admin_psswrd" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Contraseña">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="btn-submit">Acceder</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
     <script src="../js/validate_frm_login_admin.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores.

1. No esperar a que se cargue la página para empezar con el script.
2. No estás calculando la longitud de los campos con `usrAdmin.length`.

Para solucionar el 1, el final del script cámbialo por esto:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('btn-submit').onclick = function() {validarCampos()};
};
```

Si no esperas a que cargue la página completa, es posible que el botón no se haya cargado cuando el script empieza a ejecutar, por lo que a veces funcionará y otras no.

Por cierto, se puede simplificar así: 
`document.getElementById('btn-submit').onclick = validarCampos;`

Para solucionar el 2, cambia:

```
if (usrAdmin.length == 0 || psswdrAdmin.length == 0) {
```

por:

```
if (usrAdmin.value.length == 0 || psswdrAdmin.value.length == 0) {
```

Por otro lado, creo que querrás poner de rojo solo la parte que haya fallado, así que el `if-else` sería algo así:

```
if (usrAdmin.value.length == 0)
    usrAdmin.classList.add('error');
}
else {
    usrAdmin.classList.remove('error');
}
if (psswdrAdmin.value.length == 0) {
    psswdrAdmin.classList.add('error');
}
else{
    psswdrAdmin.classList.remove('error');
}
```

```js
"use strict";
    
function validarCampos() {
    var usrAdmin = document.getElementById('tb_admin_usr');
    var psswdrAdmin = document.getElementById('tb_admin_psswrd');

    if (usrAdmin.value.length == 0) {
        usrAdmin.classList.add('error');
    }
    else {
        usrAdmin.classList.remove('error');
    }

    if (psswdrAdmin.value.length == 0) {
        psswdrAdmin.classList.add('error');
    }
    else{
        psswdrAdmin.classList.remove('error');
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('btn-submit').onclick = validarCampos;
}
```

```css
.error {
    background-color: #ff7675;
    border: 1px solid #d63031;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Iniciar Sesión</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label for="tb_admin_usr">Usuario:</label>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="tb_admin_usr" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Usuario">
        </div>

        <label for="tb_admin_psswrd">Contraseña:</label>
        <div>
            <input type="password" id="tb_admin_psswrd" required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Contraseña">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" id="btn-submit">Acceder</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

He simplificado el HTML solo para el ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos opciones que no son excluyentes:

- Mover la etiqueta al final del body:

  ```
    ...
    <script src="../js/validate_frm_login_admin.js"></script>
  </body>
  ```
- Asegurarte de que tu código se ejecute al cargar toda la página, y no antes:

  ```
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    //hasta que el documento no se cargue, este código no se ejecutará
    function validarCampos() {
      var usrAdmin = document.getElementById('tb_admin_usr');
      var psswdrAdmin = document.getElementById('tb_admin_psswrd');

      if (usrAdmin.value.length == 0 || psswdrAdmin.value.length == 0) {
          usrAdmin.classList.add('error');
          psswdrAdmin.classList.add('error');
          return false;
      }
      else{
        usrAdmin.classList.remove("error");
            psswdrAdmin.classList.remove("error");

          return true;
      }
    }

    document.getElementById('btn-submit').onclick = function() {validarCampos()};

  });
  ```